# In Revelation 15:2 why is the phrase "over his mark" missing in some translations?

Tags: greek, revelation, translation-philosophy, eschatology

The following text in the book of Revelation some translators have chosen to include this phrase whilst others have left it out

KJV Revelation 15 : 2

> And I saw as it were a sea of glass mingled with fire: and them that had gotten the victory over the beast, and over his image, and ***over his mark***, and over the number of his name, stand on the sea of glass, having the harps of God.

Revelation 15:2 YLT

> and I saw as a sea of glass mingled with fire, and those who do gain the victory over the beast, and his image, and ***his mark***, [and] the number of his name, standing by the sea of the glass, having harps of God,

Revealation 15:2 NLT

> I saw before me what seemed to be a crystal sea mixed with fire. And on it stood all the people who had been victorious over the beast and his statue and the number representing his name. They were all holding harps that God had given them.

Revelation 15:2 AMP

> I saw what seemed to be a glassy sea blended with fire, and those who had come off victorious from the beast and from his statue and from the number corresponding to his name were standing beside the glassy sea, with harps of God in their hands.

Not well vexed in Greek but does the original Greek contain this phrase?

Comment: εκ του χαραγματος αυτου  is present in the [Textus Receptus](https://textusreceptusbibles.com/Interlinear/66015002) (thus present in KJV and YLT) but is omitted from the Critical Text. See Scrivener's comparison 1881. Up-voted +1.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase in Rev 15:2 καὶ ἐκ τοῦ χαράγματος ἀυτοῦ (= "and from the mark of it") is unique to the Textus Receptus and the Bibles that follow it such as the KJV, NKJV and similar.

The phrase does NOT occur in:

- NA28/UBS5 text
- W&H text
- Majority text
- Byzantine text
- Orthodox text/Patriarchal text
- etc

The origin of the phrase appears to be from the Latin Vulgate, rather than the Greek as it appears in Jerome's Vulgate and the Clementine text.  This is rather typical of the Textus Receptus which included a number of additions from the Latin that were absent in the Greek such as 1 john 5:7b, 8, etc.

Comment: Always include this link on the topic of textus receptus KJV https://bible.org/seriespage/3-kjv-rv-elegance-accuracy

Comment: @Michael16 - great reference - many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I use two (2) Latin Vulgate versions with side-by-side and interlinear-style, Latin-to-English, translations. Neither of them contain Latin equivalent wording for ἐκ τοῦ χαράγματος αὐτοῦ (ek tou charagmatos; lit., **over the mark of his**) in REV 15:2 TR1550 and KJV.